# Display text with variable white spacing?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a block of text with word-wrap but uses a variable size of white spacing so the text fills the width of the box evenly on each line. (see picture)

I'm stumped on this one and google searches haven't come up with anything.  I'm also utilizing bootstrap and jquery in the site, so if either of those can create a solution that would be fine too.

[image: no desc]

Comment: Do you mean `text-align: justify`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve], not just an image.

Comment: If I could provide an example, I wouldn't need to have asked the question.  Yes justify was it. I searched for every description I could think of and nothing ever mentioned justify. ugh figures it'd be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to justify the text. Use the `text-align: justify` to do that. More information can be found on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/).

```css
.text-justified {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: justify; /* this is the important line, it justifies the text */
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-justified">This text will be justified. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor felis et augue tristique euismod. Mauris at rutrum justo. Aenean mollis rutrum arcu, vitae feugiat dolor pharetra et. </p>
```